# Creating a new user breaking existing permissions

Tags: ssh, users, git, chmod

I have a machine running Ubuntu with a SSH config file in `~/.ssh/config` with the following permissions (default when creating a new file)

```
-rw-rw-r--  1 dev dev   75 Oct 26 20:13 config
```

After creating a new user (test) with the same primary group (dev) as the existing user (dev), I am no longer able to git clone when logged in as dev.

```
dev@vm:~$ git clone ...
Cloning into ...
Bad owner or permissions on /home/dev/.ssh/config
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Googling around seems to suggest that I can fix the ssh problem by running `chmod 600 ~/.ssh/config`, but why would this even be an issue? How can I fix this systematically, since I assume this would've affected other files too?

Thanks!

Comment: IME Ubuntu is the only distribution where `ls -ald $HOME` will show `rwxr-xr-x`.  The problem is *detected* by ssh, but the root cause is Ubuntu.  ("problem" in this case being that this new user you created can get into and change your ssh config etc)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In the openssh-7.6p1 source code file [`readconf.c`](https://salsa.debian.org/ssh-team/openssh/-/blob/debian/1%257.6p1-1/readconf.c#L1764) we can see that the permission checking is delegated to a function `secure_permissions`:

```c
if (flags & SSHCONF_CHECKPERM) {
        struct stat sb;

        if (fstat(fileno(f), &sb) == -1)
                fatal("fstat %s: %s", filename, strerror(errno));
        if (!secure_permissions(&sb, getuid()))
                fatal("Bad owner or permissions on %s", filename);
}
```

This function is in [`misc.c`](https://salsa.debian.org/ssh-team/openssh/-/blob/debian/1%257.6p1-1/misc.c#L728) and we can see that it indeed explicitly enforces one member per group if the file is group-writeable:

```c
int
secure_permissions(struct stat *st, uid_t uid)
{
        if (!platform_sys_dir_uid(st->st_uid) && st->st_uid != uid)
                return 0;
        if ((st->st_mode & 002) != 0)
                return 0;
        if ((st->st_mode & 020) != 0) {
                /* If the file is group-writable, the group in question must
                 * have exactly one member, namely the file's owner.
                 * (Zero-member groups are typically used by setgid
                 * binaries, and are unlikely to be suitable.)
                 */
                struct passwd *pw;
                struct group *gr;
                int members = 0;

                gr = getgrgid(st->st_gid);
                if (!gr)
                        return 0;

                /* Check primary group memberships. */
                while ((pw = getpwent()) != NULL) {
                        if (pw->pw_gid == gr->gr_gid) {
                                ++members;
                                if (pw->pw_uid != uid)
                                        return 0;
                        }
                }
                endpwent();

                pw = getpwuid(st->st_uid);
                if (!pw)
                        return 0;

                /* Check supplementary group memberships. */
                if (gr->gr_mem[0]) {
                        ++members;
                        if (strcmp(pw->pw_name, gr->gr_mem[0]) ||
                            gr->gr_mem[1])
                                return 0;
                }

                if (!members)
                        return 0;
        }
        return 1;
}
```

Comment: SSH is explicitly made to check the file permissions, and to complain _loudly_, if another user could modify the configuration because that would be huge gaping security hole. It probably checks the number of users in the group instead of complaining about group-writability as such, since many systems have per-user groups, and umasks allowing write access for the group and false positives there would just annoy people unnecessarily.

Comment: This seems to be Debian-specific - the [commit](https://salsa.debian.org/ssh-team/openssh/-/commit/b1033fed87fd9fa24dccab45f00cadcbc7144c47) is from Colin Watson, [the upstream bug is closed WONTFIX](https://salsa.debian.org/ssh-team/openssh/-/commit/b1033fed87fd9fa24dccab45f00cadcbc7144c47), and I couldn't find this function anywhere in https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable

Answer (score 5):

This is related to ssh. Ssh requires the file `~/.ssh/config` to be readable only by the user it affects and noone else. File-permission of 664 or 644 is default on most systems (rw-rw-r-- or rw-r--r--). You can control this by setting a umask.

`git clone` is using ssh to clone the repository, maybe it's using some ssh-stuff on init even when the clone is done from http(s).

links:

- https://wiki.debian.org/Permissions#The_defaults_for_new_files_and_directories
- https://linux.die.net/man/5/ssh_config (section “Files”)

Comment: Must be WRITABLE only by owner; readable by others is okay for config and pubkey files, including known_hosts and authorized_keys; PRIVATEKEY files must be readable only by owner (even if encrypted, which indepedently should provide confidentiality). I don't know where die.net found a _2013_ (!) man page, but see the current maintained versions at https://man.openbsd.org/ssh.1#FILES and https://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config.5#FILES